# How to get data from database to view page in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get data from database to my view page using Laravel 8.

the table's name is **"users"** **[id, name, email, etc...]** it's autogenerated from Jetstream, connection and login register works fine !

I only want to view table **users** list (**id and names**).

Here is my editprofile.blade.php file :

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Edit Profile') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
          <h1>This is a private page </h1>

          @foreach($petani as $key => $data)
              <tr>
                <th>{{$data->id}}</th>
                <th>{{$data->name}}</th>             
              </tr>
          @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my routes/web.php file
(the blade is under a folder called profile so the path is **profile/editprofile.blade.php**)

```
Route::get('profile/editprofile', function () {
$petani = DB::table('users')->get();

return view('profile/editprofile', ['petani' => $petani]);
});
```

Please how Can I show data in my page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just use Eloquent models as it's shown in the offical documentation.
So to query all users you would do something like this:

```
Route::get('profile/editprofile', function () {
  $usres = \App\User::all();
  return view('profile/editprofile', ['petani' => $usres]);
});
```

Comment: I've got this error when I tried the solution you proposed :                                                           Error
Class 'App\User' not found

Comment: Do you have User model anywhere in your application? If not, you can always create it. But try to search for it first.

Comment: Yes I have a User model created automaticlly by Jetsream

Comment: Then replace '\App\User' in my code with your model. I am not sure what the namespace is for models generated with Jetstream. It's probbaly '\App\Models\User', but again you should see it in your code more clearly.